# ООП в Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ооп

Ребята, такой абстрактный вопрос...Есть 2 класса: Маркер и Стёрка. В каждом из них реализованы свои собственные свойства и методы.

К примеру, Маркер (Marker) обладает методом draw(), который позволяет рисовать прямые линии (по заданной начальной и конечной точке).

Стёрка (Eraser) обладает методом clean(), который стирает нарисованные линии (по введённой начальной и конечной точке).

Описаны только методы (без реализации, т.к. вопрос у меня, скорее, абстрактный).

К примеру, в коде ниже, я создаю маркер зелёного цвета и рисую линию с помощью метода draw(). Затем я создаю стирку шириной 60px и стираю нарисованную линию (координаты взяты произвольно):

```javascript
function Marker(color) {
    this.color = color;
    this.draw = function (x0, y0, x1, y1) {
        //..................................
    }
}

function Eraser(width) {
    this.width = width;
    this.clean = function (x0, y0, x1, y1) {
        //..................................
    }
}

var marker = new Marker("green"); // создаю объект маркер зелёного цвета
marker.draw(30, 40, 50, 60);      // рисую прямую линию по начальной и конечной точке

var eraser = new Eraser("60px"); // создаю объект стёрка шириной 60px
eraser.clean(30, 40, 50, 60);    // стираю эту же линию
```

Теперь у меня задача создать объект 3-й объект Доска (определённой ширины и длины). Для этого я создам класс Доска (Board):

```javascript
function Board(width, height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}
```

Вопрос такой. Мне нужно нарисовать моим зелёным маркером на этой доске. Как это реализовать в виде кода? Я понимаю, что здесь нужно будет написать всего-то пару строчек кода, но всё же...(ООП только начинаю изучать, поэтому с абстракциями у меня пока плохо)

Comment: Значит метод `Рисовать` для Доски должен использовать `Маркер`. Поэтому вам надо либо передать `Маркер` в качестве аргумента метода `Рисовать` либо в конструкторе `Доски` обозначить что у нее есть `Маркер`.

Comment: +1, и на мой взгляд у *Маркера* вообще не должно быть метода *Рисовать*, а только свойства типа *Толщина линии*, *Тип линии*, *Цвет линии* и т.п. (можно взять за пример кисти в граф. редакторах). А функционал по отрисовке разместить в *Доске*, т.к. собственно она и держит информацию о нарисованных объектах. Менять *Маркер* можно будет достаточно легко, например: `board.setBrush(new Marker('green', '4px', 'solid'))` или `board.setBrush(new Pencil('black'))` или `board.setBrush(new Eraser('60px'))`, если они все будут построены по одному интерфейсу.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое ребята!

Comment: @MichaelRadionov Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде отдельного ответа.